# Test of Normal Distribution

Tags: r, normal-distribution

Before I start be easy on me I am not a stats person - I am 
just on the quest for information :-)

I was tasked to generate many graphs for someone who wanted to see if the data presented with a bell shape curve vs a graph with > 1 peak - this was no biggie but silly me I thought maybe it would be easier to run the data thru some stats package like R that would flag the populations that need to be looked at with a graph. The quest has led me to  reading Shapiro-Wilk, Anderson–Darling test etc but various people with more knowledge than I still pointed to the graphing of data as the only way to verify Normal Distribution.

So my question is is there any Statistics method I can run the following data thru to flag the data for further investigation instead of graphs ??
Instead of Counts of Patients by days should I just look at full list of DaysInHospital

Thanks

> Data is plotted with a graph per disease with the data plotted
>   x-axis - Days in Hosiptal
>   y-axis - Cnt of Patients

DiseasePopulation #1

```
( DaysinHospital,Cnt of Patients) = {(1,1),(2,1),(3,3),(4,6),(5,2),(6,1),(7,1),(8,1)}
```

DiseasePopulation #2

```
( DaysinHospital,Cnt of Patients) = {(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2),(5,6),(6,3),(7,1),(8,1)}
```

Comment: @Roland, I *think* that "DaysinHospital" is the distribution being considered here, and we are being given a tabulated variable rather than raw observations. (It also seems the OP's question is really closer to "unimodal vs multimodal" rather than "Normal vs non-Normal" ...)

Comment: The OP apparently has posted already histogram-style data - i.e. 1 observation of 1 day stays, 1 observation of 2 day stays, 3 observations of 3 day stays...

If you just used the raw observation list 'x' with only the DaysinHospital values you should be able to easily apply suitable functions - e.g. 'shapiro.test(x)' from '{stats}' or 'dip(x, ...)' from '{diptest}'.

Comment: How about a `qqplot` to compare with a standard normal dist?

Comment: Who is telling you that graphing data is the only way to test for normality? That seems like a very, very subjective method. If you found the Shapiro-Wilk test via google, you could find the `shapiro.test` in R just as easily.

Comment: @BenBolker Possibly, maybe. But if that's the case `DaysinHospital` is not a continuous variable. A discrete distribution should be used.

Comment: To be clear, by graphing I was thinking about only looking at a histogram since the OP only mentioned bell curves

Comment: to repeat: I think 'testing for normality' is a red herring, I suspect the OP really wants to test for multimodality (i.e. @CMichael's suggestion of `diptest::dip`), but "is it normal?" is the vocabulary they're working with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as R mechanics are asked you can do stuff like that (as hinted towards in my comment):

```
#raw observations of number of days in hospital
data1 = c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,7,8)
data2 = c(1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,8)

#histograms for first analysis
hist(data1,nclass=8)
hist(data2,nclass=8)

#q-q Plots for further graphic analysis
qqnorm(data2)
qqnorm(data1)

#Shapiro test from stats package
require(stats)
shapiro.test(data1)
shapiro.test(data2)

#Hartigan’s dip test statistic for unimodality from diptest
require(diptest)
dip(data1)
dip(data2)
```

For really understanding the results delivered by these tests or how to interpret the graphs you should definitely look for appropriate statistics guidance. For starters, this answer on `shapiro.test()` would be a good start:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15427746/3124909